# Calling methods and properties of reference types in generic classes

Tags: c#, .net, generics

While there are plenty of example on generics using primitve types like int ans string I couldn't really find one using proper classes. Here is the scenario

```
    //main program
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass<TClass> mt = new MyClass<TClass>();

            mt.GetValueFromType();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

This is the generic class

```
public class MyClass<T>  
{
    public void GetValueFromType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Genric method called");

         //Need to call the method MyTypeMethod() from the reference type sent in here.                
         //How?


    }
}
```

One of the types that will be sent in to the generic class as

```
public class TClass
{

    public void MyTypeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type method called");
    }
}
```

Can this even be done in C# or do I need to refer to an interface of TClass with the `new MyClass<T>().GetValueFromType()` method ?

If I have to use interface then why use generics at all?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. It seems the general agreement is to use a constraint of a base type or an interface. This leaves me wondering if  generics is useful at all or just overrated. All it looks like is alternate to using interfaces in constructors when dealing with objects. So the second part of my question still stands open. Is generics supposed to be used on reference types only for setting/returning properties and otherwise only beneficial in case of dealing with primitive types?

Answer (score 1):

All the compiler can infer is that generic parameter T is of type Object so only the methods and properties for System.Object will be available. In order to get beyond that, you need to tell the compiler that T is expected to be derived from a base type, or implements specific interfaces. This is called a generic constraint:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{

  public virtual void MyTypeMethod()
  {     
  }

}


 public class TClass : BaseClass
 {

    public override void MyTypeMethod()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Type method called");
    }

 }



public class MyClass<T> where T: BaseClass
{
    public void GetValueFromType(T value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Genric method called");
        value.MyTypeMethod();
    }
}
```

So in this example any class derived from BaseClass can be used for the generic parameter T. You can also do the same thing with an interface. But in that case it would be more along the lines of that T implements the constrained interface. Usually the interface route is much more flexible since c# does not allow multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [generic constrains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) what I think will accomplish what your after:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T: TClass
{
    public void GetValueFromType(T value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Genric method called");
        value.MyTypeMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give it a go, I think you will find it compiles perfectly.

Comment: thanks yes it does. but is it generics really if I constraint MyClass to just one class type or an interface? I might as well use GetValueFromType(ITClass value) instead of GetValueFromType(T value)

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an abstract base class, say `MyBase` that defines the method `MyTypeMethod()`:

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
    public virtual void MyTypeMethod() { }
}
```

All the classes you want to use in the generic class would inherit from this. Override and implement `MyTypeMethod()`

Modify your generic class:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : MyBase
{
    public void GetValueFromType()
    {
        T.MyTypeMethod();        
        Console.WriteLine("Generic method called");

    }
}
```

You could also use an interface as gleng suggested.